# Advanced Custom Fields | Help me link to a variable

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am struggling with appending a variable created using my Advanced Custom Fields into an OnClick attribute within a link I am creating. I simply wish to create a link that also triggers an OnClick. The OnClick's purpose is going to be to trigger a script which tracks where users have engaged with the page (this doesn't need too much depth).

I am convinced it is a syntax error which I am sure one of you wizards will have a work around for.

Here is the snippet:

```
<?php
$has_header_contact_details = get_field('has_header_contact_details', 'options'); ?>
<div class="site-contacts">
    <?php
    get_field('contact_method', 'options');
    while( have_rows('contact_method', 'options') ): the_row();
    $contact_color = get_sub_field('contact_color');
    $contact_text = get_sub_field('contact_text');
    $contact_link = get_sub_field('contact_link');
    $contact_icon = get_sub_field('contact_icon'); ?>
        <div class="site-contact">
            <a class="box-link" href="<?php echo $contact_link; ?>" target="_blank" onclick="<?php echo "track_load('https://example.com/" . echo $contact_link . "')"; ?>, <?php echo "'" . $contact_text . "'"; ?>"></a>
            <?php if($contact_icon != ''):?><img src="<?php echo $contact_icon; ?>" class="contact-icon" alt="contact icon"><?php endif; ?>
            <p<?php if($contact_color != ''):?> style="color:<?php echo $contact_color; ?>"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $contact_text; ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

The difficulty is coming from this line:

```
<a class="box-link" href="<?php echo $contact_link; ?>" target="_blank" onclick="<?php echo "track_load('https://example.com/" . echo $contact_link . "')"; ?>, <?php echo "'" . $contact_text . "'"; ?>"></a>
```

Using the variables created in php $contact_link & $contact_text. Can you help me figure out why this code above doesn’t create the output:

```
<a class="box-link" href="tel:0123456789" target="_blank" onclick="track_load('https://example.com/tel:0123456789', '0123 456 789')"></a>
```

At this point we can trust that the variables are correct as I have previously had this link working without the OnClick, massive thank you to all contributors.

Thanks, Jason.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be the extra `echo` in this part of that line:

`<?php echo "track_load('https://example.com/" . echo $contact_link . "')"; ?>`

You're using `.` to join the string parts together, so you don't also want the `echo`:

`<?php echo "track_load('https://example.com/" . $contact_link . "')"; ?>`

Hope that helps

Comment: I am going to try this now buddy and will feedback, thanks for taking a look